# Pulling in second dataset with kendodropdown make .value() to get .text()

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a dropdown that populates a kendodropdown depending on the value of the dropdown.
It calls the following function:

```
function showHideAttributes() {
    clearCover();
    const org = "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]";
    try {
        var ddl = $("#speciesAttribute").data("kendoDropDownList");
        ddl.dataSource.data([]); // clears dataSource
        ddl.text(""); // clears visible text
        ddl.value(""); // clears invisible value
    } catch (e) {}
    switch ($("#attributeType").val()) {
        case "CoverCategory":
        {
            $(".cover").removeClass("hidden");


            $.getJSON("/FormReport/GetGroundCoverCommonSpecies/" + org,
                function(data) {
                    speciesCommonData = data;

                    $("#speciesAttribute").kendoComboBox({
                        autoWidth: true,
                        dataTextField: "Text",
                        dataValueField: "Value",
                        dataSource: speciesCommonData,

                        delay: 500,
                        filter: "startswith",
                        suggest: true,
                        change: fillInData2
                    });
                });
            break;
            }
        case "CoverSpecies":
            {
                $(".cover").removeClass("hidden");
                $.getJSON("/FormReport/GetGroundCoverNRCSSpecies/" + org,
                    function(data) {
                        speciesCommonData = data;

                        $("#speciesAttribute").kendoComboBox({
                            autoWidth: true,
                            dataTextField: "Text",
                            dataValueField: "Value",
                            dataSource: speciesCommonData,

                            delay: 500,
                            filter: "startswith",
                            suggest: true,
                            change: fillInData2
                        });
                    });
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            $(".cover").addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
     
}
```

If I pick "CoverCategory" and then pick "Bare Soil" from the kendocombobox I get the following:

```
$("#speciesAttribute").data("kendoComboBox").value() // gets G_BARE which is correct
```

If I then pick "CoverSpecies" which pulls down another data and then again pick "CoverCategory" and then pick "Bare Soil" to pull in the original database I get the following:

```
$("#speciesAttribute").data("kendoComboBox").value() //gets "Bare Soil" which is the text and not the value
```

I have verified that the datasource still has the correct value.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you add the code where you try to get the value using $("#speciesAttribute").data("kendoComboBox").value() ?  Also, have you verified that the GetGroundCoverNRCSSpecies method is returning the value field and not the Text twice?

Comment: Also, is the text you get back when trying to get value one of the entries in the data list or is it a custom value? If it is a value not in the list that is how the combobox behaves - see https://www.telerik.com/forums/why-combobox-text()-is-automaticly-copied-to-value